# How to put sub-directory/sub-domain in another server (or shared hosting)

Tags: go, webserver

I have a Go server-side program hosted on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I want to handle `example.com` with Go, then `example.com/blog` or `blog.example.com` with PHP in shared hosting. 
I prefer to do this with Go itself, not with another web server (ex: Nginx),
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the endpoints served by another server/process as a reverse proxy. The standard library gives you [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy), which acts as a standard `http.Handler`, to make this very easy.

Try something like this:

```
target, err := url.Parse("http://blog.example.com/")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)

mux.Handle("/blog", proxy)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I use shared hosting's `IP address or DNS` instead of `Url`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "or DNS". The method obviously requires a parsed URL, but you can use an IP address in a URL.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote wrong.
It didn't work. Can you give a little time for chatting? PLZ